# Can't remove view from superview on reusable tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: EventCommentsCustom = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EventCommentsCustom
       guard let release = array[exist: indexPath.section] else { return cell }

    if release.user == "condition" {

                let image = UIImage()
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://example.com/" + TegKeychain.get("profile_pic")!))
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 50, height:50)
                imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
                imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
                imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
                imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
                imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                imageView.tag = 3
                cell.addSubview(imageView)

                let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 90, y: 10, width: 200, height: 50))
                button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
                button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
                button.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Say something...", comment: ""), for: .normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EventComments.openInput), for: .touchUpInside)
                button.tag = 3
                cell.addSubview(button)

    } else {

    if let viewWithTag = cell.viewWithTag(3) {
                    if viewWithTag is UIImageView {
                        print("DONE")
                        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
                }
                if let viewWithTag = cell.viewWithTag(3) {
                    if viewWithTag is UIButton {
                        print("DONE")
                        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
                }
    }

 return cell
}
```

I am trying to remove views that I created with a tag in a reusable tableview cell.

However, I still can see UIButton and UIImageview when first reused (5. section of tableview), then It starts to remove properly

Why don't they get removed at the first reuse?

Comment: Why not just use different cells?

Comment: Are you aware that you are able to design multiple custom prototype cells in the table view (since Xcode 6)? The `viewWithTag` dance is outdated.

Comment: @vadian I was thinking about the same thing. Should I just add multiple prototype cell to dynamic tableview and design them but how can I handle in cellforrowat?

Comment: Yes you should. You can distinguish the cells by the identifier and index path.

Comment: @vadian have time for a short example?

Comment: Get the item for given index path. If `item.user == "condition"` dequeue the cell with button and image view otherwise dequeue the other cell. Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that reusing in your case could mean that the image view and button get added twice for a cell. You only remove one of them though. I think you should take a different approach (like different prototype cells as `@vadian` stated) into consideration but for now (assuming my assumption is correct) you could try this to fix your problem:

Replace ...

```
if let viewWithTag = cell.viewWithTag(3) {
    if viewWithTag is UIImageView {
        print("DONE")
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
if let viewWithTag = cell.viewWithTag(3) {
    if viewWithTag is UIButton {
        print("DONE")
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

With ...

```
while let viewToRemove = cell.viewWithTag(3) {
    if viewToRemove is UIImageView || viewToRemove is UIButton {
        viewToRemove.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

**Update** - 
The approach with different cell types would look something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let release = array[exist: indexPath.section] else { return cell }

    if release.user == "condition" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OneIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! OneCustomCellType
        // configure your cell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnotherIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! AnotherCustomCellType
        // configure your cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Nevertheless think about using different prototypes for the different cell types. Makes your life easier!

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz And it would be nice if you could mark the answer as correct if it helped you... ;)

Comment: I am having 'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. ?

Comment: it is exactly as you wrote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185755/discussion-between-utku-dalmaz-and-andre-slotta).